# How to change auto import in WebStorm for types

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I have a simple example with combining two modules `m1.ts` & `m2.ts` to another one `m3.js` in TypeScript.

```
//m1.ts
export class A{}

//m2.ts
export class B{}
export class C{}

//m3.js - combine modules
export * from './m1';
export * from './m2';
```

WebStorm IDE has a hotkey **Alt + Enter** with functional to automatic find dependencies for types in other files.

Using this hot key for `A` class, IDE will automatically add `import {A} from './m1'`:

```
//m4.ts
import {A} from './m1';
import {C} from './m1';

let a = new A();
let c = new C();
```

The same situation is for other classes..

Result what I want:

```
import {A, C} from './m3';

let a = new A();
let b = new C();
```

And I didn't find any settings to change finding in `m3.ts` module.

Is it possible?